# Wrong number of columns after converting to Table Per Concrete Class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have taken a working entity class and map and converted to use a base class.

Since doing so I get "NHibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns:" on any composite user type in the descended class:

```
public SubModel : TreeNodeBase
{
   string Name { get; set; }
   Quantity Gross { get; set; }
}

public class SubModelMapping : SubclassMap<SubModel>
{
    public SubModelMapping()
    {
        Table("SubModel");

        Abstract();

        Map(x => x.Name); //normal types are fine

        Map(x => x.Gross) //this causes the error
            .LazyLoad()
            .CustomType<QuantityCompositeUserType>()
            .Columns.Clear()
            .Columns.Add("Gross_Scalar", "Gross_UoM");
    }
}

public class TreeNodeBaseMapping : ClassMap<TreeNodeBase>
{
    public TreeNodeBaseMapping()
    {
        //We are using Table Per Concrete Class inheritance

        // indicates that this class is the base
        // one for the TPC inheritance strategy and that 
        // the values of its properties should
        // be united with the values of derived classes
        UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping();

        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Level);
        References(n => n.Parent)
            .LazyLoad()
            .Nullable();
        HasMany(n => n.Children)
            .KeyColumn("Parent_id")
            .Where(x => x.Parent.Id == x.Id)
            .LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

- Worked before I changed to TPCC inheritance.
- Works if I remove any composite user type mapping.

Any idea what could cause this? Can supply the `QuantityCompositeUserType` if could be relevent.

**Edit**
SQL it creates:

```
create table SubModel(
   Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
   Name TEXT,
   Gross_Scalar NUMERIC,
   primary key (Id)
)
```

You can see that expected column `Gross_UoM` is completely missing.

Whilst if this is a regular `ClassMap`, not a `SubclassMap`,

```
create table Transactions (
   Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
   Name TEXT,
   Gross_Scalar NUMERIC,
   Gross_UoM TEXT,
   primary key (Id)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an old bug.

Checking out and building the source from github fixed the issue.

The nuget version dates from June 2012, so is very out of date. I will ask the devs when they plan to release fixes like this to nuget and will post what they say here.